# printk stopped writing to after booting into new compiled kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, syslog, printk

I have **compiled latest Linux kernel version (3.7.6)** on my VMware machine and was able to **successfully boot into new kernel**, however for some reason I am **not able to view printk messages from kernel in syslog** (I am checking /var/log/messages ), dynamically **inserted modules are not writing into syslog**

I even tried with

```
 pr_info
```

but no luck

my printk configuration seems ok with below values

```
4       4       1       7
```

moduel I am working with is also loaded whihc i can see from

```
lsmod 
and 
cat /proc/modules
```

any idea on resolution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked dmesg

Comment: then check your configuration through menu config or .config file.

Comment: which specific configuration section you are referring to, does the configuration here reflect to modules created dynamically, because as I can see prints in /var/log/messages print is enabled for compiled source CONFIG_PRINTK=y

Comment: menuconfig -> Kernel Hacking -> Enable dynamic printk() support
maybe this will work..

Comment: do you want me to recompile the entire kernel again ? Please that will be too much for this task

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30164/discussion-between-goodies-and-uday)